# smbpasswd not working with --disabled-password and --gecos ''

Tags: linux, samba

I'm trying to use smbpasswd but it's not working like I expect.
I try this:

> sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" username
>
> sudo chpasswd < <( echo 'username:testpassword' )
>
> sudo smbpasswd username

The last command is not working with this message:

> Failed to find entry for user username

While the user certainly exists, I can log in with it without problems.
what can I do to make this work? And why isn't this working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user may exist for the system, but samba does not yet know this user. So have to use `smbpasswd -a username` to define this user for samba (i.e. to 'add' this user to the known samba users).

Comment: Indeed, I totally forgot the -a. Thanks man.